# ORA - 02287 sequence number not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table name test which has three columns id, m_id and s_m_id

I am executing below query

```
select id,test.nextval listagg(m_id || ',' || s_m_id, ';') within group (order by m_id) as merge_ids 
from test t group by id
```

than I am getting error  ORA - 02287 sequence number not allowed here.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `,` or `||`.

Comment: can you please provide exact query where and what i m missing

Comment: Why use the test.nextval? Is it any purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to do too many things in one go. Create a subquery for the grouping and add the sequence numbers later:

```
select id, test.nextval, merge_ids
from (
    select id, listagg(m_id || ',' || s_m_id, ';') within group (order by m_id) as merge_ids
    from test t
    group by id
)
```

Comment: Hi Codo, I want results to come | seperated. Also by your query it will show up in individual columns

Comment: What's that to do with your original question? I understood the problem was the ORA-02287 error.

Comment: the query which you gave solved that ORA error. thanks for that. But i want the data should show up | seperated

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what result you expect. You better open a new question where you exactly describe the data you have in your table, what result the current query produces and how you'd like to have it instead.

Comment: Codo thanks for your reply i changed the query result as I wanted..your query helped me in solving the ORA error.